# C UDP client server not working

Tags: c, linux, server, udp, client

So I have one UDP server that returns the hour or the date to the client with the following code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <time.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *res;
    struct sockaddr_storage cli;
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm* timeinfo;
    char tbuffer[9];
    char buf[81], host[NI_MAXHOST], serv[NI_MAXSERV];

    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;    /* Allow IPv4 or IPv6 */
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; /* Datagram socket */
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;    /* For wildcard IP address */
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;          /* Any protocol */

    getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &res);
    int sd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, 0);
    bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
    freeaddrinfo(res);

    while(1) {
        socklen_t clen = sizeof(cli);
        int c = recvfrom(sd, buf, 80, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &cli, &clen);
        buf[c] = '\0';
        getnameinfo((struct sockaddr*) &cli, clen, host, NI_MAXHOST, serv, NI_MAXSERV, NI_NUMERICHOST);
        time(&rawtime);
        timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
        if(buf[0] == 't') {
                printf("%ld bytes de %s:%s\n", c, host, serv);
                ssize_t chars = strftime(tbuffer, sizeof(tbuffer), "%T", timeinfo);
                sendto(sd, tbuffer, chars, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cli, clen);
        } else if(buf[0] == 'd') {
                printf("%ld bytes de %s:%s\n", c, host, serv);
                ssize_t chars = strftime(tbuffer, sizeof(tbuffer), "%D", timeinfo);
                sendto(sd, tbuffer, chars, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cli, clen);
        } else if(buf[0] == 'q') {
                printf("Saliendo...\n");
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        } else {
                printf("Comando no soportado %s", buf);
        }
    }
}
```

To test the code I was using `./server <IPServerAddres> <PortAddress>` on the server side and `nc -u <IpServerAddress> <PortServer>` on the client side (another machine).

Now I want to create the UDP client UDP and do the same without using `nc`, just writing  `./client <IPServerAddres> <PortAddress> <command>` where `command` can be `t` for time `d` for date and `q` for quit, just like in the server.

Here is the code of the client program:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *res, *resp;
    int sd, j, s;
    size_t len;
    ssize_t nread, nwrite;
    char buf[500];

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s host port command...\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;    /* Allow IPv4 or IPv6 */
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; /* Datagram socket */
    hints.ai_flags = 0;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;          /* Any protocol */

    getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &res);

    for(resp = res; resp != NULL; resp = resp->ai_next) {
        sd = socket(resp->ai_family, resp->ai_socktype, resp->ai_protocol);
        if(sd == -1) {
            perror("socket()");
            continue;
        }

        if(connect(sd, resp->ai_addr, resp->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            perror("socket()");
        } else {
            break;
        }

        close(sd);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(res);

    for(j = 3; j < argc; j++) {
        len = strlen(argv[j]) + 1;
        nwrite = write(sd, argv[j], len);
        if(nwrite == -1) perror("write()");
        nread = read(sd, buf, 500);
        buf[nread] = 0;
        if(nread == -1) perror("read()");
        printf("Recibidos %ld bytes: %s\n", (long) nread, buf);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The problem is that when I try to run my client program I got no response, so I guess is in a infinite loop or something like that.

Any help will be apreciated, I'm learning C so I'm sorry for the mistakes, thank you.

EDITED: Corrected the `break` in the `for` loop in case `connect()` returns something different than -1.

Comment: Check if `resp` is NULL after the `for` loop.

Comment: I've added     `if(resp == NULL) {        
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not connect\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }` and I get the error "Could not connect", why is that?

Comment: You'll need to look at the addresses you got back from `getaddrinfo`, if any.  You could also check the return code of `getaddrinfo` and pass any non-zero return value to `gai_strerror` to get the error string.

Comment: I check now the return value of `getaddrinfo` and I've changed the `break` case if the `for` loop because it was wrong, in case `connect` return something different than -1 then the loop breaks. After this changes I got nothing when I run the program, it seems to be stuck on a infinite loop...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your calculation of the length of the message to send:

```
len = strlen(argv[j] + 1);
```

This gets the length of the string *starting from the second character*.  You want:

```
len = strlen(argv[j]) + 1;
```

This gives you the string length plus 1 for the null terminator.

Also, after reading the response, you'll need to null-terminate what you got back:

```
buf[nread] = 0;
```

Comment: That's true man, thanks, I've changed the calculation problem and the buffer null-terminate, but it keep executing as a infinite loop, I don't know why...I've edited the post with the last version of the client program, in case you see something more.